# Send email after paying with Paypal Django

Tags: python, django, paypal

I have a problem here and I don't understand why I'm not getting this to work.

I'm trying to send an email to the current login user in the Store after he makes the pay with paypal.

here is my code:

views.py

```
def send_email(**kwargs):

#Sacar el Carrito que necesitamos
user = kwargs.get('instance')
cart = Cart.objects.get(client=user)
cartitems = cart.items.all()

#Llamamos el html
ctx = {'pagesize':'A4', 'cart':cart, 'cartitems':cartitems}
html = render_to_string('frontend/order.html',ctx)

#Configuracion enviando mensaje via GMAIL
to_admin = 'sergiomonge10@gmail.com'
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject='Success Email',to=[to_admin])
msg.attach_alternative(html,'text/html')
msg.send()

payment_was_successful.connect(send_email)
payment_was_flagged.connect(send_email)
```

But is failing because it has no user. I don't know why. Any help will be appreciate

Comment: Estas seguro que la señal si se ejecuta? Are you sure that the signal is called?

Comment: Yes it does, and the payment get succesfull, but when the paypal site redirects to my site the signal payment_was_successful.connect(send_email) should do the work but it sends an error, and its because cart = Cart.objects.get(client=user) there is no cart because there is no User :S thats what I need, Si hablo español. xD

Comment: Ok so you have to debug, before **user=...** put  print kwargs, dir(kwargs.get('instance')), and tell me what it prints, Lo supuse por los comentarios de el código :)

Comment: The response is None. Cart matching query does not exist. And the error is here "cart = Cart.objects.get(client=user) ", Por cierto te mande una invitacion a facebook, ya que veo que eres djanguero

Comment: No, but  **print kwargs, dir(kwargs.get('instance'))**  what does  this print? Al rato te acepto, si soy djanguero :)

Comment: {'signal': <django.dispatch.dispatcher.Signal object at 0x102468250>, 'sender': <PayPalIPN: <IPN: Transaction 6DS13043DJ596492T>>} ['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__'] this is what I get. Tienes skype?

Comment: As you can see the **kwargs** argument has not an **instance** so as you do not have an instance  there is no user and therefore there is no cart, Si tengo pero te lo paso por facebook , estoy en mi trabajo al rato mejor hablamos por facebook y ya por ahí te ayudo y pongo la respuesta aqui si es que la encontramos

Comment: ok buddy thanks, I'll be watching facebook, waiting your response.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [doc](https://github.com/spookylukey/django-paypal/blob/master/paypal/pro/models.py#L69) the model `PayPalNVP` has an field `user` that is a `ForeignKey` to the django's `User`, so for use this you have to use the `signals` in `paypal.pro`

```
from paypal.pro.signals import payment_was_successful, payment_was_flagged
```

and then  into `send_email` function you only put:

```
user = kwargs.get('sender').user
```